# Calculate the generating function gn of Xn and calculate g(t)=limn→∞gn(t)

Tags: probability-theory

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $X_n$ be binomial distributed with parameters $(n, p_n)$, with $np_n = \lambda > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Calculate the generating function $g_n$ of $X_n$ and calculate $g(t) = \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(t)$ for $t \in [-1, 1]$. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to the moment generating function, you get
$$g_n(t)=E[e^{tX_n}]=E[e^{t(Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_n)}]=E[\prod_i^n e^{tY_i}]
=\prod_i^nE[e^{tY_i}]$$ $$=(1-p_n +p_ne^t)^n$$
Where the $Y$'s are i.i.d Bernoulli$(p_n)$ random variables. With this we get
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}g_n(t)=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{\lambda e^t-\lambda}{n})^n=\exp(\lambda(e^t-1))$$